# Can not re-order "Customizable Options" on "Simple Products"

Tags: magento2, admin, sorting, simple-product, customizable-options

I recently upgraded from Magento 2.3.x to 2.4.5. Bit of a hassle but got basically everything working.

One issue I am having is with the "Customizable Options" section when creating or editing a "Simple Product". The Option groups themselves are not draggable to re-order (they use to be), the Group I select to drag just freezes in place. However if I open a group I can click and drag to re-order any of the items in the group just fine. I'll add an animated Gif to show what I mean.

[image: Option Groups are not draggable while Options in the groups are.]

I have included the console in the gif to show that there are no errors being generated so I am having trouble figuring out the issue. The 1 warning on the console is just the JQuery Migrate warning.

Any suggestion on a solution would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems is fixed in 2.4.6 https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36289 here is the github issue and fix I am also facing this issue, and a post by Mark Shust on how to create a patch from it if you can't update to 2.4.6 https://markshust.com/2019/08/26/apply-magento-2-patch-github-pull-request/